# Cordova and socket.io : client disconnection and reconnection

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I am trying to share datas between a cordova app (android) and a node server, but the client doesn't stop disconnect and reconnect...

Also, I can't get any information from the server (probably because the client disconnects too fast).

Here's my simple server :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('new connected : ' + socket.id);

  socket.emit('connected', {"data": "YEAAAAH"});

  socket.on('slt', ( data ) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("disconnection");
  });
});
```

And the code i use for the client app :

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script>

let socket = io.connect('http://MY-DOMAIN-NAME.com');

socket.on('connected', function (data) {
    alert('connected');
    socket.emit('slt', { data: 'slt' });
});
```

And a picture of the logs after 5 sec... :
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iggkb.png)

Do you have an idea how to fix that ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem fixed : I messed up for linking my scripts :/